# UploadPhoto To Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

i have my models and everything like this,  when i'm trying to upload a Image this is what i got:

```
'PhotoSerializer' object has no attribute '_committed
```

My view:

```
class UploadPhoto(APIView):
    #authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = ()#(IsAuthenticated,)

    def put(self, request, username):

        user = User.objects.get(username = username)
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user= user)
        photo = PhotoSerializer(data = request.data)
        userprofile.photo = photo
        userprofile.save()
        return Response(status= status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Serializer:

```
class PhotoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'photo',
        )
```

And at least my Model.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """
    User Profile

    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M')

    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',message="Phone must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up 15 digits allowed.")
    #The Field on DataBase after check if it's a valid Phone Number.
    # validators should be a list
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=True) 
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/', null = True)

    driver_passenger = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    rides_given = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    rides_taken = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reputation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I tried some options to upload a photo, but I couldn't implemented so I appreciate your help (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a little of trying I Could, upload the Image With this
code hope is useful

View.py

```
class UploadPhoto(APIView):
    #authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = ()#(IsAuthenticated,)

    def put(self, request, username):

        user = User.objects.get(username = username)
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user= user)
        photo = PhotoSerializer(userprofile,data = request.data)
        photo.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        photo.save()

        return Response(status= status.HTTP_200_OK)
```